# RTTY translation, multiline

Tags: arrays, timer, arduino, char

I'm trying to adapt [KG4SGP](https://github.com/kg4sgp/arduino-rtty)'s RTTY modulator to send a textfile instead of a fixed char array. I'm getting Strings by the readLine() method, altering these Strings by replacing certain values and then copy the altered String to a charArray.

I changed his global`char msg[] = "\n\nCQ CQ CQ DE KG4SGP KG4SGP KG4SGP KN\n\n";` to`char msg[70];` and hoped to have this running instead;

```
while(text.available()) {
   String lin= readLine();
           lin.toLowerCase();
               if (lin.indexOf("&")) {
                 if (lin.indexOf("&de ")) {
                    lin.replace("&de ", "de ");
                    result = calculateDayOfYear(dag,maand,jaar);
                    lin.replace("juldate" , String(result)); 
                    lin.replace("hour", String(uur));
                    lin.replace("min", String(mins));
                 } 
                 if (lin.indexOf("month")) {
                    lin.replace("&","");
                    lin.replace("day", String(dag));
                    lin.replace("hour", String(uur));
                    rmin=random(1, mins);
                    lin.replace("rndmin", String(rmin));
                    lin.replace("month", (months[maand-1]));
                    lin.replace("year", kortjaar );
                 }
                    lin.toUpperCase();
                    lin.toCharArray(msg,lin.length()+1);
                    //Serial.println(msg);
              }
```

Well, whatever I did or tried, I'm never getting any charArray to correctly identify the current character and translate it.. :-( It seems to all come out of the timerfunction
All suggestions welcome

Comment: For one thing, you won't replace anything unless "&" appears in the string, so if you were expecting an uppercase string copied to an array, that could explain it.

Comment: So sorry, was being busy to ask a 'good' question since yesterday, lin.toUpperCase and to charArray were moved outside of 'íf-statement, but even these lines won't be translated